# Type A female USB port

Tags: usb

I ordered a Type A USB port because I thought all Type A USB ports were the same, come to find out after taking the laptop completely apart that the 4 prong 2.0 USB port I ordered was way different than the type A 2.0 USB I needed for the laptop, So I took apart a flash drive and that's also way different than the other 2

The one I order on amazon is the same size as the one I needed for the laptop, but the very end of the new one where the prongs are isn't recessed to go half way into the logic board

Does anyone know where I can find laptop Type A USB ports for a HP G7
you can probably tell that the one i need is the one closest to you and the one i ordered is the one furthest away

[image]

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing up something such as through-hole vs surface mount parts, or mounting lugs, or even some kind of notch-in-the-board mounting height.  At any rate, this is a prohibited "shopping question".  You might try a larger online catalog (digikey, etc) and try to find something with a similar picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several types of Type-A receptacles that differ in mounting options, even with through-hole pins. In addition to the "standard type" (which you got, "through-hole right angle"), there are several other options: "board edge-mounting", "board edge with cutout", two types of "vertical mount", and, very important, "reverse mount". Your part looks like a "board edge with cut-out", normal mount, but I am not sure. Check with Mouser or Digi-key (or Arrow/Vertical/Avnet/etc) who offer genuine brand connectors, and never use Amazon/eBay/aliexpress - they likely sell some bootleg parts that use bad plating, bad contact springs, may have bad dimension tolerance, and use bad (melting) plastics.

Comment: I tried looking on digikey and I couldn't find any type-a USB ports

Comment: So what about Arrow or Vertical or Avnet as mentioned?

Comment: @hellomoto, try harder, https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/usb-dvi-hdmi-connectors/312?k=&pkeyword=&pv29=10&sf=0&FV=ffe00138%2C700368

Comment: @SolarMike, what about the list? They don't have the best search engines nor image presentations, but they won't sell you some knock offs.

Comment: @Ale..chenski not sure what you want from me, I was suggesting that the OP should check the other suppliers you gave in your post and you made the same point with “try harder” in your comment...

Comment: @SolarMike, sorry, I misunderstood. You didn't use "@hellomoto" tag, so I assumed that your remark was somehow addressed only to me, that something is wrong with my answer...